# Is there any way to get Virtual Box seamless to work on the secondary monitor?

Tags: virtualbox

Is there any trick or setting that would allow Virtual Box seamless windows to work on the secondary monitor?

As it stands seamless windows seem restricted to the primary window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this ticket](http://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/2720) (the second comment).

> Seamless mode currently does not work
>   on the second monitor of a dual head
>   setup. This is a known limitation.

Comment: Just came across this by chance, and wanted to say that it seems to work just fine these days (with Linux host and windows guest).